# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object ? when i using pluck()

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
     Trying to get property 'name' of non-object? when i using pluck() for retrive data from database

//a.contoller       
     public function index(){
      $insurance = Insurance_Providers::pluck('id','name');
      $physicians = Physicians::pluck('id','pp','sp');
      $pharmacies = Pharmacies::pluck('id','name');
      return view('auth.profile',compact('insurance','physicians','pharmacies'));
    }

//a.blade.php
    <select name="insurance" id="ip" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">Insurance Provider</option>
     @foreach($insurance as $pro)   <option value="{{ $pro->name }}">{{ $pro->name }}</option>
     @endforeach
     </select>
```

Trying to get property 'name' of non-object? when i using pluck() for retrive data from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using three parameters in pluck,

```
$insurance = Insurance_Providers::pluck('name', 'id'); // name is value and id is key
```

In blade do this,

```
@foreach($insurance as $pro)   
    <option value="{{ $pro }}">{{ $pro }}</option>
@endforeach
```

It should work.

First parameter is value and second is key